# Akeneo PIM Import Images Issue

Tags: file-upload, akeneo, pim

I'm trying to import my products via excel or CSV file but the images is not imported in pim.
I am specifying the image URL for the images but it is not rendering the image i have to do it manually for each product please help me Thank you in advance

Comment: yes now its working for me.  you can not import the images in pim via url you have do it with zip

Answer (score 0):

What are your PIM version, please? :)
You could see it on your dashboard page, in the footer.

As this feature has changed a lot between versions, I want to share the answer adapted to your version.

Comment: I am using. Version: CE 4.0.68